# Extract Triples From RDF File With Multiple Ontology

Tags: java, extract, rdf, jena, triples

I need a source code with java and jena (or other languages) that ables to extract triples from a RDF file that has multiple ontology.

There is a source code in [This Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669422/how-to-extract-rdf-triples-from-xml-file-using-existing-ontology-in-java) but this code needs to determine an ontology in source code.

I need a source code that itself read ontology from rdf files and print Sujects,Predicate and Objects as string in URL format.

This is my rdf file: [My Files](http://ramezani-cs.persiangig.com/1.rdf)

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to have the same code as in here:

[How to extract RDF triples from xml file using existing Ontology in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669422/how-to-extract-rdf-triples-from-xml-file-using-existing-ontology-in-java)

But without the predicate that filters the statements. For example ...

```
FileManager fManager = FileManager.get();
Model model = fManager.loadModel("some_file.rdf");
SimpleSelector selector = new SimpleSelector(null, null, (RDFNode)null) {
    public boolean selects(Statement s)
        { return true; }
}

StmtIterator iter = model.listStatements(selector);
while(it.hasNext()) {
   Statement stmt = iter.nextStatement();
   System.out.print(stmt.getSubject().toString());
   System.out.print(stmt.getPredicate().toString());
   System.out.println(stmt.getObject().toString());
}
```

If this is not what you need, please explain your question in further detail. I do not fully understand it.