# Jena nested properties

Tags: rdf, jena, semantic-web

How could I generate by code nested properties please? Like that:

```xml
<geo:Departement rdf:about="DEP_05">
    <geo:code_departement>05</geo:code_departement>
    <geo:subdivision>
        <geo:Arrondissement rdf:about="ARR_051">
            <geo:code_arrondissement>051</geo:code_arrondissement>
            <geo:nom xml:lang="fr">Briançon</geo:nom>
        </geo:Arrondissement>
    </geo:subdivision>
    <geo:subdivision>
        <geo:Arrondissement rdf:about="ARR_052">
            <geo:code_arrondissement>052</geo:code_arrondissement>
            <geo:nom xml:lang="fr">Gap</geo:nom>
        </geo:Arrondissement>
    </geo:subdivision>
</geo:Departement>
```

All my properties (created using "createProperty") are at the same level.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear exactly what you mean by subproperties.  It's important to realize that RDF is a *graph-based* data representation based on labeled, directed, edges called triples of the form:

> subject predicate object

Your data for instance, includes the triples

```
DEP_05 rdf:type                 geo:Department
DEP_05 geo:code_department      "05"
DEP_05 subdivision              ARR_O51
ARR_051 rdf:type                geo:Arrondissement 
ARR_051 geo:code_arrondissement "051"
```

RDF/XML provides lots of different ways to write the same graph.  For instance, one way of writing your data (I've added the appropriate prefixes) is:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:geo="https://stackoverflow.com/q/21383685/1281433/">
  <geo:Departement rdf:about="https://stackoverflow.com/q/21383685/1281433/DEP_05">
    <geo:code_departement>05</geo:code_departement>
    <geo:subdivision>
      <geo:Arrondissement rdf:about="https://stackoverflow.com/q/21383685/1281433/ARR_051">
        <geo:code_arrondissement>051</geo:code_arrondissement>
        <geo:nom xml:lang="fr">Briançon</geo:nom>
      </geo:Arrondissement>
    </geo:subdivision>
    <geo:subdivision>
      <geo:Arrondissement rdf:about="https://stackoverflow.com/q/21383685/1281433/ARR_052">
        <geo:code_arrondissement>052</geo:code_arrondissement>
        <geo:nom xml:lang="fr">Gap</geo:nom>
      </geo:Arrondissement>
    </geo:subdivision>
  </geo:Departement>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Another way, which happens to use fewer of the "shortcuts" that RDF/XML allows, is:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:geo="https://stackoverflow.com/q/21383685/1281433/" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="https://stackoverflow.com/q/21383685/1281433/ARR_052">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="https://stackoverflow.com/q/21383685/1281433/Arrondissement"/>
    <geo:code_arrondissement>052</geo:code_arrondissement>
    <geo:nom xml:lang="fr">Gap</geo:nom>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="https://stackoverflow.com/q/21383685/1281433/ARR_051">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="https://stackoverflow.com/q/21383685/1281433/Arrondissement"/>
    <geo:code_arrondissement>051</geo:code_arrondissement>
    <geo:nom xml:lang="fr">Briançon</geo:nom>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="https://stackoverflow.com/q/21383685/1281433/DEP_05">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="https://stackoverflow.com/q/21383685/1281433/Departement"/>
    <geo:code_departement>05</geo:code_departement>
    <geo:subdivision rdf:resource="https://stackoverflow.com/q/21383685/1281433/ARR_051"/>
    <geo:subdivision rdf:resource="https://stackoverflow.com/q/21383685/1281433/ARR_052"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Even though these are different *XML* documents, they are serializations of the same RDF graph.  There are non-XML serializations as well.  In the Turtle serialization, your data is:

```
@prefix geo:   <https://stackoverflow.com/q/21383685/1281433/> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

geo:ARR_051  a                   geo:Arrondissement ;
        geo:code_arrondissement  "051" ;
        geo:nom                  "Briançon"@fr .

geo:DEP_05  a                 geo:Departement ;
        geo:code_departement  "05" ;
        geo:subdivision       geo:ARR_051 , geo:ARR_052 .

geo:ARR_052  a                   geo:Arrondissement ;
        geo:code_arrondissement  "052" ;
        geo:nom                  "Gap"@fr .
```

It's very important to realize that these are all the *same* graph.  An RDF processing tool *doesn't care* which one you use.  That said, it can be nice to use a format that's more human-readable, so I tend to prefer Turtle.  If you still need to use RDF/XML, then you may way to serialize your model using the "RDF/XML-ABBREV" language.  To do this, specify `"RDF/XML-ABBREV"` as the `lang` argument to [Model.write(OutputStream out, String lang)](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#write%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29).  From the Javadoc:

> #### [write](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#write%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29)
>
> ```
> Model write(OutputStream out, String lang)
> ```
>
> Write a serialized represention of this model in a specified language.
>
> The language in which to write the model is specified by the lang
>   argument. Predefined values are "RDF/XML", "RDF/XML-ABBREV",
>   "N-TRIPLE", "TURTLE", (and "TTL") and "N3". The default value,
>   represented by null, is "RDF/XML".
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - out - The output stream to which the RDF is written
> - lang - The output language
>
> **Returns:**
>
> - This model

### Related Questions

Some related questions have arisen here before, and you might find some of them helpful.  The ones that I quickly found are:

- [Why some rdf files does not contain <rdf:Description rdf:about=...>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18204160/1281433)
- [How to access OWL documents using XPath in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17036871/1281433)

Comment: Thanks Joshua for that complete answer. In fact I've got 3 properties, each available for different dates and I wanted to group them by date. But when you began speaking of triples I realized that it was not a correct RDF-way-of-thinking, indeed. So I factorized everything at the same level:

<prop1_year1>...</>
<prop2_year1>...</>
<prop1_year2>...</>
<prop2_year2>...</>

...and so on. Not beautiful, but efficient.

Comment: @paradise I have to admit, I'm not quite sure what your solution is.  Think of RDF triples as short sentences.  If you have a relationship that's between more than two things, you might have a look at [Defining N-ary Relations on the Semantic Web](http://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/).

Comment: What I needed:
    "<subject> <has> <property>" --> for year 2002, 2008 and 2010.

How I did: 
    "<subject> <has_in_2002> <property>
    <subject> <has_in_2008> <property>
    <subject> <has_in_2010> <property>"

Not extensible, but that was not the purpose.

Comment: @paradise Triples have a subject, a predicate (also called property), and an object, e.g., `:john :hasName "John"`.  `:john` is the subject, `:hasName` is the predicate/property, and `"John"` is the object. I think you're saying "property" where I'd expect to hear "object".  If I understand you correctly, you need to represent a 3-place relationship: has(subject,time,object) — the subject has object at the time.  If that's the case, you really should take a look at the [defining n-ary relations](http://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/). If that's what you intend, I'll update my answer.