# RDF::Redland::Model how to add tag <foaf::nick>

Tags: perl, rdf, redland

I have a loaded an `RDF::Redland::Model` parsed from an RDF/XML document and I want to add tag `<foaf::nick>` in it.  How can I do it?

#### Update:

This is my code so far:

```
my $st = RDF::Redland::Node->new_xml_literal("<foaf:nick>content</foaf:content>");
$self->{Model}->add_typed_literal_statement($st);
print $self->{Model}->to_string;
```

and it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Reasons for closing questions include: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance," and "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."  What have you tried so far?  Which methods in [`RDF::Redland::Model`](http://search.cpan.org/~djbeckett/Redland-1.0.5.4/perl/lib/RDF/Redland/Model.pm) have you used? What didn't work?

Comment: Thank you for updating your question to show code, but what does “this doesn't work” mean?  Did the code cause an error?  Does it run without a problem, but the printed results are different from what you expect?  What is actually failing?

Comment: Please mark blocks of code in your question with four leading spaces.  You may way to read the [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  I just fixed your code to use this convention, since you had used the blockquoting (starting lines with `>`), which kept the `<foaf:nick>...</foaf:content>` from appearing.

Comment: Define "doesn't work."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RDF models don't contain tags (or even XML elements);  an RDF model is a set of triples of the form `subject predicate object`.  [foaf:nick](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/#term_nick) is a property that relates a [foaf:Person](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/#term_Person) to a nickname.  Based on the title of your question, it sounds like that what you want to do is add a triple `something foaf:nick somenick` to the model.  In this case, the documentation for [RDF::Redland::Model](http://search.cpan.org/~djbeckett/Redland-1.0.5.4/perl/lib/RDF/Redland/Model.pm) indicates that what you'll want is either `add` or `add_typed_literal_statement`:

> #### add SUBJECT PREDICATE OBJECT
>
> Add a new statement to the model with
>   SUBJECT, PREDICATE and OBJECT. These can be RDF::Redland::Node,
>   RDF::Redland::URI or perl URI objects.
>
> #### add_typed_literal_statement SUBJECT PREDICATE STRING [XML_LANGUAGE [DATATYPE]]
>
> Add a new statement to the model containing a typed
>   literal string object STRING with (optional) XML language (xml:lang
>   attribute) XML_LANGUAGE and (optional) datatype URI DATATYPE.
>   XML_LANGUAGE or DATATYPE can either or both be set to undef.

In the first case, it appears that you'd need to create a [RDF::Redland::Node](http://search.cpan.org/~djbeckett/Redland-1.0.5.4/perl/lib/RDF/Redland/Node.pm) to represent the literal string that is the nickname. There is [a constructor](http://search.cpan.org/~djbeckett/Redland-1.0.5.4/perl/lib/RDF/Redland/Node.pm#CONSTRUCTORS) that take a string argument  In the second case, which is probably easier, you can just use the string directly.

#### Edit

Now that you've posted your code, the particular issue becomes clearer, though you still haven't mentioned what's actually going wrong.

```
my $st = RDF::Redland::Node->new_xml_literal("<foaf:nick>content</foaf:content>");
$self->{Model}->add_typed_literal_statement($st);
```

First, if I understand what you're trying to do, the XML content that you've used isn't well formed, as the opening and closing tags don't match (`nick` is not `content`).  More problematically, this isn't how RDF works.  RDF is a *graph-oriented* representation, where the basic concept is a statement of the form

```
subject predicate object
```

and an RDF graph, or model, is a set of these.  Viewing each statement as a directed labelled edge from subject to object, we obtain a graph.  RDF models can be serialized in a number of formats, one of which is [RDF/XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-rdf-syntax/), which is also the one that you're working with.  However, as I've pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17052385/1281433), the point of an RDF API is to let you work with the statements of an RDF graph, and to not be concerned with the particular serialization of the graph.

It sounds like you want to add a statement

```
$something foaf:nick "content"
```

to the graph, for some subject which you haven't identified.  According to the documentation that I linked to and quoted above, `add_typed_literal_statement` takes *three* arguments, not one, and the third argument should be a string.  Your second line should look something like:

```
$self->{Model}->add_typed_literal_statement($subject,$foafNick,"content");
```

where `$subject` and `$foafNick` are URI [Nodes](http://search.cpan.org/~djbeckett/Redland-1.0.5.4/perl/lib/RDF/Redland/Node.pm).  E.g., you might do this (untested):

```
$subject = new RDF::Redland::URINode("https://stackoverflow.com/users/400371");
$foafNick = new RDF::Redland::URINode("http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/nick");
$self->{Model}->add_typed_literal_statement($subject,$foafNick,"Nikita");
```

to add the triple

```
<https://stackoverflow.com/users/400371> foaf:nick "Nikita"
```

to the model.