# How to attach or merge XML file to a PDF in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, pdf

I have a PDF file and I want to attach / merge / embed an XML file what containt the same datas like PDF but readable for computers. Is there any way in PHP to do this?

I don't have any code or idea how to start this.

Thanks!

Comment: You would also need to design a client that knows how to extract the attached xml.

Comment: @Anthony Its pretty clear, that you have no clue about this topic and have not read my answer. **What has this question to do with a client?** I've already described a reader/writer in my answer. You are implicitly adding something, which was never asked and is not the problem. So why did you close this? And all the others: this is lemming like close clicking. Open your eyes.

Comment: why is my question off-topic? This is a programmer q-a forum... isn't it? Where I need to ask my question if not here when I don't have idea how to start? by the way... here on the stackoverflow isn't answer to my question. And to the end: this is not a server-client problem. This is a programming problem.

Comment: @jens - if the OP adds an attachment and sends it to 100 people and none of them have a client that can detach the data, then whether a client exists is pretty important. Kind if like not making an HTML page with extra elements no browser supports. And I wrote one sentence as a comment, maybe you need to chill out.

Comment: @Anthony: but I want not to extract the attached xml. I want to attach a xml.

Comment: And what will happen later with the attached data?

Comment: @Anthony: other softwares read and parse it, that is not my business. I just looking for a simple and clear way to transfer my offers, orders, invocies, etc datas what can read softwares and humans too. The PDF is a simple and clear way to read for humans. XML is a good solution for sowftwares. And now I want to combine both solutions.

Comment: I don't think this is off topic.  I think the question just needs edited.  My customer is asking me to embed XML in a pdf invoice so they can write software to pull the information straight into a system - isn't that what this question is about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to store the XML inside a XMP block in the PDF.
XMP is a metadata extension. It allows to define own Schemas.
Basically it's RDF/XML.

SPEC: http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/xmp/sdk/XMPspecification.pdf

I have not seen a XMP writer for PDF in PHP, yet.
But it can't be that hard to implement it.
When looking at the reader, it's basically RDF content wrapped inside a `<x:xmpmeta` block.

Some pointers:

- Reader - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1578326/1163786
- Reader - http://surniaulula.com/2013/04/09/read-adobe-xmp-xml-in-php/
- [Writer - XMP on JPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668132/)
- PHP Extensions

  - http://www.alexander-block.net/Beruflich/eZ-Systems/XMP-Erweiterung-fuer-PHP
  - http://www.alexander-block.net/content/download/484/2299/file/xmp_php_ext-0.0.2.tar.bz2
  - http://xmpphptoolkit.sourceforge.net/

---

Another solution would be to use PDF "attachments".

You could work with the PHP lib FPDF. Here is an example to add an attachment:

- http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script95.php