# merge equivalent classes using owl API

Tags: java, semantic-web, ontology, owl

I used OWL API to merge 2 owl files correctly. However I discovered that classes/entities withe the same name(Joshua helped to define it this way: prefixes defined such that the suffix of the classes' IRIs equal under a case insensitive string comparison) are repeated. I need to output these classes with the same names as one. any help will be appreciated.
thank you in advance.

Comment: "but am getting errors using it." I don't see any errors in this question, and there's not enough code to run the entire example (nor do I have access to the files that you're working with).  "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance."  Can you include the error messages with stack trace?

Comment: This seems like it's a duplicate, or an elaboration on your earlier question [merging two owl files and eliminate common classes in one file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19280857/1281433).  Can you respond to the requests for clarification there, please?  It's not clear what your error is in this new question (because you haven't shown us), but I expect that a bit more clarification on that old question  might remove the need for this one.

Comment: Seconded. "am getting errors" is not specific enough to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: In your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19280857/1281433) (of which this might be a duplicate, since they're clearly about the same task, and neither has an answer), you mentioned using Jena, but now you've got only OWL-API.  Is Jena still an option?

Comment: Yes. If it could help me achieve the result.