# Stop EasyRDF from nesting resources

Tags: php, xml, rdf, blank-nodes, easyrdf

I have an RDF graph that I create with EasyRDF:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
> <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
>          xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
>          xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
>
>   <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://the-query-url">
>     <dc:creator>me</dc:creator>
>     <foaf:primaryTopic rdf:resource="genid1">
>   </rdf:Description>
>
>   <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="genid1">
>     <!-- stuff -->
>   </rdf:Description>
> </rdf:RDF>
> ```

The above is not correct - the reference to the blank node in `foaf:primaryTopic` should be `_:genid1`.

When I change that line to

```
$meta_block->add('foaf:primaryTopic', $graph->resource('_:' . $symbol_block->getBNodeId()));
```

EasyRdf nests the resources, like this:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
> <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
>          xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
>          xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
>
>   <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://the-query-url">
>     <dc:creator>me</dc:creator>
>     <foaf:primaryTopic>
>       <rdf:Description>
>         <!-- stuff -->
>       </rdf:Description>
>     </foaf:primaryTopic>
>   </rdf:Description>
> </rdf:RDF>
> ```

How do I stop EasyRdf from nesting the nodes?
I want the output to be just like the first example, only with `_:genid1` as resource for the `foaf:primaryTopic`.

Answer (score 1):

You may be misunderstanding the RDF data model.  Blank nodes are actually blank.  While the might have something like a blank node id in a particular serialization or with a given API, it's not actually part of the data model.  In the first snippet you've shown, the node with the genid nodeId *is* the object of the the foaf:primaryTopic triple.  It's the same in the second snippet too; there's a foaf:primaryTopic triple, and the object is a blank node.  You're getting the *same* RDF content. This might be easier to see if you serialize in a more human readable format, like Turtle, or N-Triples.  For more about this issue, you may find some of the discussion in [How to access OWL documents using XPath in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036871/how-to-access-owl-documents-using-xpath-in-java) useful.

All that said, you probably *can* customize how easyRDF writes RDF/XML.  It's not a library I've used, but you might look into seeing whether you can turn off syntactic abbreviations.  For instance, with Jena (a Java library), you can specify that you want "RDF/XML" or "RDF/XML-ABBREV".  RDF/XML-ABBREV is more like your second snippet, whereas it looks like you want something more like RDF/XML.  But again, I do suggest that you try serializing to a format like N-Triples or Turtle, to see that the RDF content is actually the same.  RDF doesn't have any blank node ids; that's just a concept in serializations that have to be able to refer to them.